# Google Cloud - Project "Submit for verification" doesn't appear

Tags: google-cloud-platform

"Submit for verification" button doesn't appear after fill in information and selecting scope for my project.

We are trying to connect BigQuery to Azure Data Factory.
To be able for the 3rd party developer to work properly on collecting the data, we need to make the project "internal".
To make the project "internal", we need a Google Workspace User - except that we don't know who is the workspace user within my company.

I reached out to Google Support and they advised us to Submit the project for verification.

I followed the steps communicated by Google Support.

You can apply for verification again in the Google Cloud Console. Please note the following information:
•   If scopes are selected, the scope justification fields must be filled out in order to trigger the ‘Submit for verification’ button to appear.
o   Example: My app will use https://mail.google.com/ to read, compose, send, and permanently delete from Gmail. I will need read in order to____ so that my app can ****. I will need compose in order too****, I will need send in order to____, and I will need to delete in order to____.The reason a narrower scope would not be sufficient is because ____.

After selecting a scope, I don't have a pop-up window to fill in the scope justification.
And the "Submit for verification" button doesn't appear.

Comment: Internal apps don't that's why you don't see that button

Comment: Thank you for your help! The app is set as external for now, and I still don't see the button.